# Groups with a R.E. set of defining relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Reading around I found the following two assertion:

1) Every *countable abelian* group has a *recursively enumerable* set of defining relations.

2) Every *countable locally finite* group has a *recursively enumerable* set of defining relations.

How can we prove this *directly*?

We need to find an algorithm which halts exactly when we give as input a relation of the group. As concern abelian groups, I was thinking in this way:

If $w$ is an element of the free group of countable rank, then:

- If $w$ is a commutator (I think we can check this in a finite number of steps), halt.
- If $w$ is not a commutator, then?

And for countable locally finite groups?

Comment: There is a source of confusion when you talk about "having a r.e. set of defining relations". If you deal with finitely generated groups, it is implicit that a finite generating family is given, and actually the existence of a r.e. set of relators does not depend on this choice. But for a countable group, things are sensitive of the given generating family. So you should ask about the existence of a generating sequence over which there is there is a r.e. set of defining relations.

Comment: But I believe it is still true that if an r.e. set of defining relators exists over the (possibly infinite) generating set $X$ then there is recursive set of defining relators over $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe these claims. Notice that, for any set $X$ of prime numbers, we can build a countable, abelian, locally finite group in which $X$ is the set of primes that occur as orders of elements.  Just take the direct sum (not product, because I want it to be countable and locally finite) of cyclic groups $\mathbb Z/p$ for all $p\in X$.  By varying $X$, we get uncountably many non-isomorphic groups of this sort.  But there are only countably many recursively enumerable sets, so I don't see how you could have r.e. sets of relations to define all these groups.

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2414348?uid=3738296&uid=381335053&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21102851924527

I think this is the answer.

Comment: Higman does not claim that every countable abelian group has a recursively enumerable presentation. He says that every such group *can be embedded in a group* with a recursively enumerable presentation, which then implies that it can be embedded in a finitely presented group. Similarly for countable locally finite groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt But Higman's embedding theorem states that a group has a recursively enumerable presentation if and only if it can be embedded into a group with a finite presentation. So if a group $H$ is embeddable into a group $G$ recursively enumerable presentation then it is also embeddable into a group $F$ with finite presentation, and so the group we started with $H$ has a recursively enumerable presentation. No?

Comment: @user1729: the theorem you claim of Higman is not correct as you state it. The $\Rightarrow$ part is the deep part and is indeed true. But the $\Leftarrow$ part is only true (and easy) for finitely generated subgroups of f.p. groups.

Comment: @Yves Ah, okay, I had noticed the finitely generated assumption elsewhere but hadn't realised/had forgotten it wasn't in Higman's original theorem. Thanks. I'll not forget that again!

Comment: You're right guys, thanks!

Comment: PS: in $\Rightarrow$ in Higman's theorem, there is a reduction from the case of countable groups to the case of f.g. groups, and this reduction comes before Higman's theorem: namely, the proof by Higman-Neumann-Neumann that every countable group embeds into a finitely generated group is so explicit that it immediately entails that every countable group with a recursive presentation embeds into a finitely generated recursively presented group.